# Знаки препинания после двоеточия (пояснение)

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, двоеточие

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания. Предложение изменила на более простое, но сути это не меняет.

Еще он не любил кошек () они очень свободолюбивые () и собак.

У меня есть несколько вариантов:

1. Еще он не любил кошек: они очень свободолюбивые и собак.

Но смущает отсутствие знака перед "и". По ощущениям, там должно что-то стоять.

2. Еще он не любил кошек: они очень свободолюбивые, - и собак.

Часто вижу такую расстановку знаков после двоеточия, но не уверена, что она здесь уместна. В правилах не нашла примеров с однородными членами.

3. Еще он не любил кошек - они очень свободолюбивые - и собак.

Этот вариант кажется самым простым и логичным, но можно ли это считать вставной конструкцией?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: *Еще он не любил кошек – **они очень свободолюбивые** – и собак.*

**1. Грамматика**

Основное предложение: ***Еще он не любил кошек  и собак.***

Вставная конструкция: **они очень свободолюбивые.**

**2. Правила**

Розенталь § 26. Вводные и вставные конструкции
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Пункт 1. Вставные предложения и словосочетания вносят в основное предложение **дополнительные сведения** (замечания, уточнения, **пояснения**, поправки и т. 3.

В данном случае вставка имеет **пояснительный** характер (почему не любил).

Пункт 4(1) **С обеих сторон ставится только тире**, если в месте вставки не было никакого знака препинания: *Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — **её детские ножки едва шумели по густой траве** — и вышла из чащи подле самого старика* (Т.);

В заданном предложении, как и в приведенном здесь примере,  два тире  используются при наличии **союза И.**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138848/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Answer (score 4):

oleedd, **кошками интересуетесь**? Давайте я вам все про них расскажу. Ваше предложение имеет **три варианта оформления.**

(1) *Ещё он не любил кошек: **они очень свободолюбивые**.*

**Нам важна причина?** Тогда ставим двоеточие. Интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю, вторая часть выделена.

(2) *Ещё он не любил кошек — **они очень свободолюбивые**.*

**Нам важен факт,** причина на втором месте? Тогда ставим тире, это присоединительная конструкция. По правилам Розенталя тире может заменять двоеточие. Пауза меньше, чем в первом случае.

(3) *Ещё он не любил кошек, **они очень свободолюбивые**.*

**Ничего не хотим подчеркивать?** Тогда ставим присоединительную запятую. Второе предложение просто продолжает тему первого, пауза четко не обозначается.

Как видите, **я от ответа не увиливаю.** Но вот понравился ли вам мой ответ?

@Лиза, sorry for the digression.

Comment: Тире интонационное. Те присоединительные конструкции у Розенталя не являются простыми предложениями, если вы о той теме. Жаль, что пример не привели. В вариантах 2 и 3 допускается, что то просто факт о кошках.

Comment: *По правилам Розенталя тире может заменять двоеточие* — там есть чёткие пункты, не любое двоеточие и не в любых ситуациях. В каждом случае есть лучший вариант, а другой может быть неудачным.

Comment: *Нам важна причина?* — по-моему, здесь явно важна причина. Кто ещё так не считает?

Comment: А знаете что... А вы хитры. Вы опять увильнули от вопроса, максимально ловко. И почти получилось. Прочитайте ещё раз мой вопрос.

Comment: Лучше вы почитайте: 4. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с причинно-следственными отношениями. Ср.: Последние дни флажки на карте не двигались: положение оставалось без перемен (Сим.); А углубляться мы не могли — земля промёрзла (Гран.). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189  А в этом предложении у вас опять ляп: Ещё он не любил кошек: они очень свободолюбивые, — а мне они нравятся.  Надо так: Ещё он не любил кошек—они очень свободолюбивые, — а мне они нравятся. И спокойной вам ночи:))

Comment: В этом примере Розенталя тоже интонационное тире, но не собираюсь об этом спорить, хотя доказать могу (оно того не стоит). Сами вы ляп. Важна причина, поэтому поставил двоеточие. Я же не говорю, что ваш вариант ошибочен, почему вы мой бракуете (он абсолютно корректный, пункт в ответе указан)? Не увиливайте от моего вопроса: какой знак вы бы поставили в моём примере и почему? Только честно.

Comment: Все добрые христиане давно спят, а завтра у меня выходной от этого форума. Послезавтра, наверное, тоже.  Я не могу отвечать на все вопросы, когда остальная аудитория абсолютно к ним равнодушна. Пока! Приятных вам собеседников, если уж я вас не устраиваю.

Comment: Вы вправе ответить тогда, когда захотите. Главное — ответить в принципе. С чего вы взяли, что не устраиваете? Тогда бы не продолжал комментировать. Новый способ увиливания?

Comment: *Нам важен факт, причина на втором месте?* — факта нет, для него не хватает "потому что". Факт — это нечто чёткое, слова в нём не опускают, ваш "факт" висит в воздухе без союза. Вы попробуйте применить такой "факт" в юридических документах, это не прокатит, без слов, указывающих на причину. Да и ваш "факт" двусмысленный. Факты такими не бывают. Смешнее всего то, что факт заключается как раз в причине, а вы противопоставляете одно другому.

Comment: Смотрите, в чём дело. В примере Розенталя реально два факта: *1) А углубляться мы не могли — 2) земля промёрзла.* Вполне можно независимо сообщить о том, что земля промёрзла. А у вас получается неправильный факт: *1) Еще он не любил кошек — 2) они очень свободолюбивые.* Факт в том, что кошки очень свободолюбивые. Но ведь нам не это нужно сказать. Эта информация не является независимой. Хочется верить, что до вас дошло.

Comment: oleedd,  вы на этих кошках просто зациклились, так что у вас  в голове сформировались прочные нейронные связи. Может быть, вам завести себе кошку, чтобы понять, насколько она свободолюбива. А ведь вопрос был не о кошках, а о правильной структуре предложения. Другими словами, о грамматике,  в то время как лексическое наполнение предложения не имело значения. Из вопроса: "Предложение изменила на более простое, но сути это не меняет". Хорошего вам дня, а также привет остальным участникам форума, которые не проявили к  кошкам должного внимания.

Comment: Не на кошках, а на такой структуре (как раз грамматика).

Comment: Грамматика – это синтаксис, а вы им не увлекаетесь (сами же говорили). А там изучаются стандартные грамматические модели, а без них никуда. Без них – одни только фантазии на тему правописания и грамматики. Или вот "ИНТОНАЦИОННОЕ ТИРЕ".  Да в общем случае любой знак интонационный, а тире бывает основным знаком. неосновным знаком, а также авторским. Интонационное тире - это вообще  частный термин, оно может по желанию автора отделять любую часть предложения. А здесь у вас оно откуда взялось? Надо иметь чувство ответственности, то есть отвечать за правильность каждого слова и каждой фразы.

Comment: Не только синтаксис. Имею в виду строение сложного предложения, а не простого (синтаксис). Не буду спорить о тире. Это надо расписывать все его официальные функции и показать, что ни одна из них здесь не подходит. Вы лучше выберите знак в моём примере и объясните выбор. *Надо иметь чувство ответственности, то есть отвечать за правильность каждого слова и каждой фразы* — да что вы говорите, вы не раз бросали свои ответы, после того как обнаруживалось, что в них не всё правильно.

Comment: Вы меня с кем-то путаете, ага?  Я – это вообще воплощенная ответственность, как мне кажется ;)) Если речь, конечно,  о моих ответах, а не о комментариях. А комментарии не предназначены для расширенных дискуссий.  Задавайте вопросы, и желающие на них ответят.  Вы же напоминаете мне одну мою ученицу, с которой я очень долго занималась. Вот она говорила: "Ты – моя!". А я – не ваша.

Comment: Свои ответы вы не раз бросали в беде, уже со счёта сбился. Зачем мне желающие? Он лично вам адресован. По вашим действиям можно создать методичку "100 способов уйти от ответа" или "Увиливание от ответа от а до я".

Comment: Вы так и не поняли: я – не ваша.  У меня нет  личной обязанности отвечать на все ваши вопросы и разбираться с  вашими примерами.   Вы же мне у.е. не платите. Поэтому  отвечаю на то, что знаю и что мне интересно.

Comment: Нет, вы не отвечаете, чтобы не дискредитировать ваш ответ. +1 способ увиливания.

Comment: Этот мой вопрос непосредственно касается вашего ответа, и вы знаете об этом. На такие вопросы необходимо отвечать, иначе вы не защищаете свой ответ и делаете его сомнительным для остальных.

Comment: Моему ответу уже ничего не поможет. Он был ясным и прозрачным, как стеклышко, понятным даже ребенку, А вы его своими 4-мя ответами так заляпали, что его и не видно. Теперь он уж точно стал сомнительным для остальных, Ну ладно, пока, до новых встреч.

Comment: Истину не заляпаешь: она безупречна, — значит, не истина.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь всё гораздо сложнее.

В примерах Розенталя реально два факта:
*1) Последние дни флажки на карте не двигались: 2) положение оставалось без перемен.*
Можно независимо сообщить о том, что положение оставалось без перемен.
*1) А углубляться мы не могли — 2) земля промёрзла.*
Можно независимо сообщить о том, что земля промёрзла.

В данном примере так не получается:
*1) Ещё он не любил кошек — 2) они очень свободолюбивые.*
Нельзя независимо сообщить о том, что кошки очень свободолюбивые.
Потому что здесь смысл в том, что это причина. Без этого (указания на причину) эта информация не нужна (нам не нужен факт, что кошки очень свободолюбивые).
Из-за этого нельзя оформить отдельными предложениями:
*Ещё он не любил кошек. Они очень свободолюбивые.*
А примеры Розенталя можно.

Поэтому тире в этом примере лучше не ставить. А то грамматика на стороне того, что это просто факт о кошках, а не причина.

Самый лучший вариант оформления исходного предложения такой:
*Ещё он не любил кошек (потому что они очень свободолюбивые) и собак.*
Это естественный русский язык.

Причину с помощью двоеточия включают в основное предложение, когда она в самом конце.

Без двоеточия, "потому что", "поскольку" или "так как" это не причина, а независимый факт в плане грамматики. А нам он сам по себе не нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Надо так:
*Ещё он не любил кошек: (потому что) они очень свободолюбивые — и собак.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150,6 — пункт 6.

У Розенталя есть такой пример:
*Что касается другого основного вопроса избирательной кампании: надо ли укреплять
самостоятельность канадской экономики, — то оказалось, что предыдущие выборы ничему не научили либеральную партию.*
Перед словом "то" ставится запятая, а перед "и" она не нужна.

Ещё у него есть такие примеры:
*Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте?

Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо* (Максим Горький).
*И много у него добра: мехов, атласа, серебра — и на виду и под замками* (Пушкин).

С двумя тире получится не причина, а просто информация о кошках.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо за помощь, но во все приведенные Вами примеры по смыслу и формулировке в корне отличаются от моего. В этом-то и проблема: я знаю, какие знаки ставятся в приведенных Вами предложениях (или, по крайней мере, смогу их найти в случае чего), но не могу понять, как правильно расставлять знаки при однородных существительных. В 6 пункте просто сказано, что при указании причины ставится двоеточие.

Comment: В Ваших примерах, грубо говоря, после тире идет продолжение мысли. А в моем - это однородные члены предложения.

Comment: В вашем примере тоже продолжается простое предложение: *Ещё он не любил кошек и собак.* Разницы нет. Чтобы продолжить предложение (после пояснительного блока), ставят тире. А как именно оно продолжается, не важно. Оно может продолжаться новым простым предложением: *Ещё он не любил кошек: они очень свободолюбивые, — а мне они нравятся.*

Answer (score 2):

Почему два тире не очень удачны?

Потому что у нас не просто пояснение, а конкретно причина. На причину обычно указывают с помощью двоеточия, "потому что", "поскольку", "из-за того что" или "так как".

При двух тире не исключается вариант, что то просто факт о кошках. А двусмысленность — это почти как стилистическая ошибка.

Да и хочу задать вопрос всем. Какой знак вы бы поставили в этом примере?
*Ещё он не любил кошек (?) они очень свободолюбивые.*
То, что основное предложение продолжается, не должно влиять на пунктуацию.

Постановка тире после "кошек" соответствует постановке запятой в этом:
*Ещё он не любил кошек, они очень свободолюбивые.* || Так ведь тоже можно.
Тире вставки сопоставимы с запятыми (в справочнике даже говорится, что имеет место использование запятых вместо тире), просто их используют, чтобы показать, где основное предложение.
В примере выше тоже неясно (нет чёткости), причина или просто факт о кошках.

Answer (score 2):

Касательно варианта (3) Sharon.

Долго анализировал и пришёл к такому выводу:
В предложениях типа:
*Он мне не нравится, он сидел в тюрьме.* || Не нравится в общем, а не из-за этого.
*Не люблю лимоны, в них нет сладости.

У нас мало денег, холодильник стоил дорого.

Печенье закончилось, кому-то оно сильно понравилось.*
после запятой не прямая причина, а то, что просто поспособствовало (прямая причина другая либо неизвестна). "Потому что" или "из-за того что" добавить не хочется, поэтому пишут просто через запятую.

Update:
**Но если мы говорим о ком-то (*он*), то, скорее всего, мы не знаем, что там чему способствовало, у нас есть факт (*он не любил кошек*) и чёткая причина (*они очень свободолюбивые*). Их нужно связать грамматически.**